# h:commandButton fails in h:form after navigating from f:ajax request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm facing a wicked little problem, which has eluded me for almost 2 days now. I got a p:treeTable component, which serves as a method of navigating and editing a hierarchical data structure. The tree is displayed on the left side. By selecting a tree entry, the user selects an entry for editing, which is then displayed in the form on the right hand. There is also a button for adding new child nodes on the entry. Clicking this will create a new subnode of the selected node and the form on the right displays the new node.

The tree is realized as a custom tag. It has a mode property, which allows me to re-use it for simple navigation or editing by handing in a binding called "mode". Here's an excerpt from the tree component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    ...
    xmlns:ticker="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/ticker/">
    <h:body>
        <composite:interface>
            <composite:attribute name="mode" required="true" />
        </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
            <h:form id="tickeruebersicht">
                <p:treeTable id="treetable" 
                    binding="#{treeNavigationController.treeTable}" 
                    value="#{treeNavigationController.root}" 
                    var="node" selectionMode="'single'}" 
                    selection="#{treeNavigationController.selection}">

                ...
                    <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.mode == 'editor'}">
                        <p:ajax event="select" 
                            listener="#{tickerUI.onNodeSelect}" 
                            update=":tickerEditForm"/>
            </c:if>

                 ...

                    <p:column style="width:5%" rendered="#{cc.attrs.mode == 'editor'}">
                        <h:commandLink title="new child node" 
                            action="#{tickerUI.createNewChildNode}"
                            styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" 
                            style="display:inline-block;">
                    <f:param name="parentNodeType" value="#{node.class.name}"/>
                            <f:param name="parentNodeID" value="#{node.id}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                    ...
                </p:treeTable>
            </h:form>
    </composite:implementation>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The imporant bits are prepared out. The navigation in the selection case works by using a p:ajax. Because the form with the id tickerEditForm is not visible unless you're on the right page, the c:if controls the inclusion of the ajax event. The navigation when adding a new child node works using a h:commandLink instead.

The form that is controlled in this fashion looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition template="template/master_layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    ...
    xmlns:ticker="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/ticker">

    <ui:define name="leftcolumn">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="leftColumn">
            <ticker:tickertree mode="editor" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:define>

    ...

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="tickerEditForm" acceptcharset="UTF-8">

            <ui:fragment rendered="#{tickerUI.ticker != null}">

                ...

                <span class="message">
                    <h:messages globalOnly="true" />
                </span>

                <ui:fragment rendered="#{tickerUI.neuerTicker}">
                ...
                </ui:fragment>

                <p class="inputLeft">
                    <h:outputLabel for="name">
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </h:outputLabel>
                                #{' '}
                    <h:inputText id="name" requiredMessage="Must enter name"
                                 value="#{tickerUI.ticker.label}" required="true">
                    </h:inputText>
                </p>

                ...

                <ui:fragment id="zusatzdaten">
                    <fieldset class="clear">
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{tickerUI.editComponentName != null}">
                            <ui:include src="#{tickerUI.editComponentName}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </fieldset>
                </ui:fragment>

                <div class="controls">
                    <span class="save"> 
                        <h:commandButton
                            action="#{tickerUI.saveAction}" value="speichern" />
                    </span> 
                    <span class="cancel"> 
                        <h:commandButton
                            action="#{tickerUI.createNewChildNode}" value="abbrechen" />
                    </span> 
                    <span class="delete"> 
                        <h:commandButton
                            action="#{tickerUI.deleteAction}" value="löschen"
                            disabled="#{not empty tickerUI.ticker.descendants or tickerUI.neuerTicker}" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ui:fragment>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:debug />

</ui:composition>
```

The big problem is, that when navigating to the form using the h:commandLink, hitting the 'Save'-button on the form calls the action method as expected. If I navigate to the form using the p:ajax instead, the form's backing bean is newly constructed, of course the data lost and the save action is not called. Both backing beans (tickerUI and treeNavigationController) are @ViewScoped. I tried going @SessionScoped to see if that made a difference, but no difference. Using Mojarra 2.2.3 and Primefaces 3.5 on Tomcat 6.

Neither me nor any of my colleagues here who worked with JSF can figure out what is going on. Can someone see what the problem is?

Comment: 'If I navigate to the form using the `p:ajax` instead, the form's backing bean is newly constructed, of course the data lost and the save action is not called.'. That's not the expected behaviour using `@ViewScoped`. No, unless you're returning something different from empty/null in your `onNodeSelect` method. However, the `p:ajax` wrapped in `c:if` tag is a bit suspicious. Have you given it a try without that? What are you using to render your page template? `ui:include`? Have you tried starting from a basic embedded `h:form` instead of all this complex template hierarchy? Minimize your code!

Comment: I took the project over as it was and already chucked out a large amount of code and hierarchy. Some can not be avoided. The rendering is done using a template and using ui:include/ui:define and ui:include. Why should that make a difference? I'm probably deperate enough to try. 

As for the c:if : it is required because without it, the tree component can not be re-used. Simply because the form referenced in the ajax update does not exist by the time the tree is rendered and JSF gets all uppety about that sort of thing.

Comment: Update:I put it all together in one component, no ui:include or custom  tag. Just the tree and the edit form in the same .xhtml. Problem persists.

Comment: So you say `tickerUI` bean is being rebuilt even if you change it to `@SessionScoped`? That makes no sense at all. Mojarra JSF 2.x early implementations used to [bring problems](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm) with `@ViewScoped` using it with taghandlers, but I think it should be solved for 2.2.3. Definitely you seem to be suffering a JavaScript error while your page updates and that's because you can't reach your bean. Can you give a try to firebug? Also check what id is tickerEditForm taking at client side.

Comment: Now that I put all of this in the same page, switching to @SessionScoped again (just double checking) causes the error: " Component ID tickeruebersicht:treetable:j_idt27 has already been found in the view.". ?!? And I did check Firebug, no javascript errors. All seems well.

Comment: You definitely have a problem inside the built-in `p:treetable`. You should try commenting your code till you have a basic tree which works, then uncomment it until you have the error again. However, I guess it is related with the `c:if` you have inside it. Taghandlers and components have [different working lifecycles](http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) and you have to consider it. Definitely you can avoid using `c:if`, just write two identical components, one of them with ajax behaviour, and render it only when you want (using `rendered` attribute).

Comment: I removed the c:if taghandler and excluded all rendered="" attributes. There are no conditionals left in the one I am using now. The tree contains simply two columns, one displaying a label and the other the commandLink. The p:ajax is unchanged otherwise. The problem remains.

Comment: Another update: I replaced the p:ajax with a command link in the cell where the label is. When setting the form up this way, things work as expected. I can't use this though, because it messes with the tree's appearance too much and leaves the navigation jumping around (after the command link the tree re-displays itself and scrolls the "selected" entry out of sight). So it is most definitely the p:ajax causing the problem here. Any more ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: More info: it must be connected with Ajax. I replaced the h:commandLink for selecting an entry with p:commandLink update=":tickerEditForm" and the link is not working either.

Comment: Try wrapping everything in the same form, as jsf seems to have some problems updating other form components. Take care of removing `tickeruebersicht` form tags in order to avoid nested forms. Wrap your `ui:fragment` in an `h:panelGroup` instead and try updating it from the same form. That should work properly. Can't do much more with your provided code :-(

Comment: What code do you need? The managed beans? As for the two forms, that i can not do. Because of the way the master template works. The two parts need to be in different ui:defines.

Comment: Well, I was talking about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which is copy'paste'runnable for every user here, removing the needing of the rest of the layers of the example you provided. What you should do: Start a basic example with two forms and try to make one update the other one. When you achieve it, try to migrate it to your real case. Otherwise, if you don't know the real cause of the issue you'll keep hanging around it for ages :-(

Comment: Contrary to me previous comment (which I just deleted because it was wrong), this does NOT work either. I still had the h:commandLink in there. The status quo is: p:treeTable updating h:form through Ajax does NOT WORK. It updates the form, but it also seems to trash the backing bean. And it doesn't seem to matter, if it's one form or many forms.

Comment: Isn't it a problem about what are you sending to the BB? `p:ajax` provides a `process` attribute, which defines what you want to send to the BB in that request. Could it be a trouble about the bean not being properly updated? Try with `process='@form'` as it defaults to `@this`. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyPartialSubmit.jsf

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out and the bean is properly updated. Even the form is updated. The trouble is, that the NEXT submit request fails because the bean seems to be destroyed by the ajax request. I also noticed, that this happened on the update already, when I used p:commandLink instead. If all the links in the tree are ajax links or event triggers, the tickerUI is created from scratch EVERY TIME. There must be some kind of bug in JSF/Primefaces.

Comment: If you're able to create an SSCCE where you reproduce the error with the minimal code, I can test it by myself. Provide me something testable without any dependency to your code. First of all you should trust on the frameworks themselves. If you can provide it I'll be able to test with Mojarra 2.1.x and PF 3.5.

Comment: That's very kind of you. I'll try to get round to it tomorrow.

Comment: AFAIK @BalusC stated many times that JSTL (c:if) should be avoided in JSF2 applications. Use rendered attribute instead. You can also try using p:commandButton with ajax="true" instead of h:commandButton.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, but as I said in the comments, I removed the c:if. It's still not working. As for the commandButton ... I don't have any command buttons in my example. Only commandLink. And I tried both h:commandLink and p:commandLink. The former works, the latter fails.

Comment: I have created a SSCCE, which demonstrates this problem.The project can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40133183/treetable-sscce.tar.gz

Comment: After much experimentation, I got *something* to work when using one form. It's not pretty and the web-designer had to do some patching up, but it seems to work. I believe the problem has something to do with the problem described in http://www.irian.at/de/blog/-/blogs/jsf-ajax-and-multiple-forms