# p:treeTable expands closed branches again

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am populating a p:treeTable with a large hierarchy of objects. One column contains a h:commandLink, which triggers an update of the form which is on the right hand side.

First I expand a first branch in the tree with 50 or so objects. Then I collapse it again. The I click on a second branch, which again opens 50 or so entries. Then I select one of those objects in the second branch and the page updates. What happens now, is that the **first branch is expanded again** and of course the second branch is scrolled out of sight.

This is unexpected and to the user potentially very annoying behaviour. Is there anything I can do to prevent the p:treeTable from doing that?

Comment: How are you updating the page?

Comment: Since p:commandLink or p:ajax do not work in my case (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977361/hcommandbutton-fails-in-hform-after-navigating-from-fajax-request) I am using h:commandLink. Aka: standard navigation with the whole page being reloaded I believe.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? I am seeing it in a normal p:tree.

Comment: I accidentally fixed mine by adding collapse/expand listeners. I have no idea why it worked.